# Salesforce Touch - What objects are available from the iPad?

Tags: touch

I'm using Salesforce Touch for the iPad but I can not access some standard objects such as campaigns, cases, and contracts. It is not possible to access these objects in Salesforce Touch?

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange @SusanaLopes. I hope this information helps you out. Stick around and check out the site. We have a really helpful community here.

Answer (score 5):

You should have access to some of those objects. From the [Spring 13 release notes](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_spring13_release_notes.pdf):

> Salesforce Touch doesn’t have all of the functionality of the full Salesforce site. Users can work with their accounts (including
>   person accounts), cases, contacts, dashboards, leads, opportunities, tasks, and all custom tabs, and they can view any events
>   that are accessible from Open Activities or Activity History related lists. With a few exceptions, all of the standard and custom
>   fields for these objects are available. Additionally, users can see their Chatter data, including People, Groups, and feeds.

It looks like Campaigns and Contracts are not available. Cases are available.